# ROS wiki engine

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What wiki engine is [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) based on?
Is it MoinMoin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59382/ros-wiki-engine/) by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your guess is right. http://www.ros.org/wiki/MoinMoin

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1